# How do I specify column names in Liquibase when creating view?

Tags: java, database, junit, liquibase

I have a database view which selects two columns from two different tables with the same name.

For example generating a DDL for the view would generate the following:

```
create view MYSCHEMA.VPRODUCTS ("Name", "AlternameName"...) AS
A.Name,
B.Name,
from  PRODUCTSA A&#13;
left join PRODUCTSB B&#13;
...
```

When I run the command to generate a Liquibase change set, the SQL in the  tag only contains a select statement for the two columns and makes no distinction for the unique column name (i.e. "Name", "AlternameName").

```
<createView viewName="VPRODUCTS ">SELECT  &#13;
A.Name&#13;
,B.Name&#13;
from PRODUCTSA A&#13;
left join PRODUCTSB B&#13;
...
```

As a result, whenever I try to execute the change set Liquibase complains about duplicate entries for columns with the same name.

I can fix this by adding SQL "AS" statements in the  tag, but I'd prefer if there was a better way to do this.

```
<createView viewName="VPRODUCTS ">SELECT  &#13;
A.Name&#13;
,B.Name AS AlternateName &#13;
from PRODUCTSA A&#13;
left join PRODUCTSB B&#13;
...
```

Is there an attribute or tag that would allow me to specify the column names when creating the view, or providing the raw SQL in the DDL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't another way. Liquibase simply passes the nested SELECT statement into the create view statement so whatever is required in the select needs to be part of the query. There is no built-in pre-processing of the view statement beyond pre-pending "CREATE VIEW X"

If you want to provide the raw SQL you can always use the  tag.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to use subselects, like this:

```
SELECT [COLUMNLIST 1:1 RENAMED] FROM (your view)
```

Or use `WITH` blocks along the same line of thinking.